# How to add value from one array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

**edit #3**
in the interest of getting better help (THANK YOU for the patience) i want to combine these two scripts:

SCRIPT 1:

```
//get csv file and set up array
        d3.csv('../mapdata/mapdatatest.csv', function (csv) {

            var rid = [],
                lat = [],
                lon = [],
                pinclr = [],
                name = [],
                str = [],
                citystzip = [],
                phone = [],
            lastinspturl = [],
            lastinspctdt = [];

            csv.map(function (d) {
                rid.push(d.rid).toString();
                lat.push(d.lat).toString();
                lon.push(d.lon).toString();
                pinclr.push(d.pinclr).toString();
                name.push(d.name).toString();
                str.push(d.str).toString();
                citystzip.push(d.citystzip).toString();
                phone.push(d.phone).toString();
                lastinspturl.push(d.lastinspturl).toString();
                lastinspctdt.push(d.lastinspctdt).toString();

               for (i = 0; i < rid.length; i++) {

                   var points = ('"' + lat[i] + "," + lon[i] + '"');

                }

            });
        });
```

SCRIPT 2:

```
    deCarta.Core.Configuration.clientName = Config.clientName;
            deCarta.Core.Configuration.clientPassword = Config.clientPassword;

            var center = new deCarta.Core.Position(Config.position);

            var pinOverlay = new deCarta.Core.MapOverlay({
                name: "Pins"
            });

            window.map = new deCarta.Core.Map({
                id: "mapContainer",
                autoResize: true,
                zoom: 11,
                center: center,
                onReady: function (map) {
                    map.addLayer(pinOverlay);

                    postPins();
                }
            });

            function postPins() {

                var points = {
                    "points": [
//i have typed in these values for testing purposes only
                        "47.15211, -97.570039",
    "48.625045, -101.375369",
    "48.39679, -101.052669"]
                };


                for (var i = 0; i < points.points.length;) {

                    pos = new deCarta.Core.Position(points.points[i]);

                    pin = pin = new deCarta.Core.Pin({
                        position: center.clone(),
                        text: 'pin: ' + (points.points[i]),
                        position: pos
                        // imageSrc: 'img/pin.png'
                    });
                    pinOverlay.addObject(pin);
                    i++;
                }

                var view = new deCarta.Core.BoundingBox(points.points);
                var centerAndZoom = view.getIdealCenterAndZoom(window.map);
                map.zoomTo(centerAndZoom.zoom);
                map.centerOn(centerAndZoom.center);

            }
```

THE RESULT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE:

instead of using typed in values as i'm doing in SCRIPT 2 -- i want those values to be fed in from SCRIPT 1.

so

```
var points = {
                    "points": [
//i have typed in these values for testing purposes only
                        "47.15211, -97.570039",
    "48.625045, -101.375369",
    "48.39679, -101.052669"]
                };
```

needs to be

```
var points = {
                    "points": [
THE "point" VALUES FROM THE SCRIPT 1 loop]
                };
```

i get the concept, can't seem to get the syntax right...tried all the suggestions, the push();, read a lot of articles, samples...i needed this 10 hours ago, any assistance will be greatly appreciated. i'd vote you up if i had enough rep yet :) thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: "the stand alone code to read the csv into an array works perfectly." Based on the 'array' you posted, I would disagree. You should assemble your data from the csv file into a structure that allows you to access the contents without any further processing. Post your csv code.

Comment: It appears that you want to learn how to add values to an existing array. You want to use `arr.push(new_value)` in that case. Please have a look at a JavaScript tutorial which covers the basics about arrays, for example: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html.

Comment: Felix, thank you for the link! i've bookmarked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding your questions.  Does this help at all:

```
var points = { 
  "points": [ 
    "47.15211, -97.570039", 
    "48.625045, -101.375369", 
    "48.39679, -101.052669"
  ] 
};

console.log(points.points);

var array = points.points;
var array_len = array.length;

for(var i = 0; i < array_len; ++i)
{
  var str = array[i];
  console.log(str);
}

--output:--

[ '47.15211, -97.570039',
  '48.625045, -101.375369',
  '48.39679, -101.052669' ]
47.15211, -97.570039
48.625045, -101.375369
48.39679, -101.052669
```

======

> i built on another page:

That is troublesome. Are you aware that the web is *stateless*?  That means that once a user leaves a page, no data is saved on the user's computer.  There are some ways around that: you can save small bits of information in cookies, or a page can send the data to a server side script, and then the server side script can save the data in a file or a database.

On the other hand, if by "on another page" you mean another javascript file, then start simpler.  Combine both javascript files into one file and get that to work, e.g.:

```
func1(a, b) = {
    ....
    return results;
}

func2(x, y, z) = {

   info = func1(x, y) + z

   //do something with info
}
```

Then it's a just a matter of putting func1 and func2 into separate files and including both of them in an html page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js1.js'></script>
```

Just make sure you get the order right: if  function in js1.js calls a function defined in js2.js, then js2.js needs to be included first.

====

html.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js2.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js.js'></script>

  <style type='text/css'>
    .colorText {
      color: blue; 
    }
    .surprise {
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="show_results" class="colorText">Hello world</div>

</body>
</html>
```

js.js

```
function do_stuff(x, y, z) {
  //send two of this function's arguments to another function
  //defined in another script:
  var results = do_other_stuff(x, y);
  return results + z; 
}

//This function will execute once the html page loads:
window.onload = function() {

  var my_results = do_stuff(10, 20, 30);
  alert("Inserting results in <div>");

  //The following div won't exist until after the page loads:
  var div = document.getElementById('show_results');
  div.innerHTML = my_results;

}
```

If the window.onload thing is too confusing, just get rid of it and use alert()'s to show the results (or any other info you are interested in).

js2.js

```
function do_other_stuff(x, y) {
  return x+y;
}
```

Now, if you want to pass just one thing to the do_other_stuff() function, e.g. your object (things with braces around them are called 'objects'), you can rewrite your scripts like this:

js.js

```
function do_stuff() {  

    var points = { 
        "points": [ 
        "47.15211, -97.570039", 
        "48.625045, -101.375369", 
        "48.39679, -101.052669" ] 
    };

    do_other_stuff(points);

}


do_stuff();
```

Then rewrite do_other_stuff() to look like this:

js2.js

```
function do_other_stuff(points_obj) {

  //do stuff with points_obj, e.g.
  alert( points_obj.points[0] );

}
```

In this example, the scripts aren't operating on any of the html elements, so there is no need to wait for the page to load.

====

See if the following comments help:
1) This loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < rid.length; i++) {

    var points = ('"' + lat[i] + "," + lon[i] + '"');

}
```

is equivalent to:

```
var points = '"' + lat[rid.length] + "," + lon[rid.length] + '"';
```

2) The thing you are doing with the quotes there is really ugly. If you are just trying to turn some numbers into a string, you can do this:

```
var point = lat[i] + ", " + lon[i];
```

js can't add a number and a string together, so js makes the assumption that you are trying to create a string, and js converts the number to a string then adds the strings together. Check this out:

```
var str = 3 + ', ' + 2;
var arr = [str];
console.log(arr);

--output:--
[ '3, 2' ]
```

3) You probably want to do something like this:

```
var points = []

for (i = 0; i < rid.length; i++) {

    points.push( lat[i] + ", " + lon[i] );

}
```

4) Then to pass the points array to your deCarta stuff, you can do this:

```
var points = []

for (i = 0; i < rid.length; i++) {

    points.push( lat[i] + ", " + lon[i] );

}

do_stuff(points);
```

And then you would define do_stuff() like this:

```
function do_stuff(the_points) {

    //Do all your deCarta stuff here

    window.map = new deCarta.Core.Map({
                id: "mapContainer",
                autoResize: true,
                zoom: 11,
                center: center,
                onReady: function (map) {
                    map.addLayer(pinOverlay);

                    postPins();
                }
            });

            function postPins() {
               console.log(the_points); //You have access to the points array
               obj = {"points": the_points};
```

=======

1) When you call a function, js lines up the function call with the function definition:

```
         do_stuff(10, 20, 30)  <----function call
function do_stuff( x,  y,  z) {...}  <---function definition
```

Then javascript does these assignments:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
var z = 30;
```

2) Then inside the function, you use the variables x, y, and z to refer to those values.

3) In the code I posted, the function call and function definition look like this:

```
         do_stuff(points)
function do_stuff(the_points) {...}
```

So js does this assignment:

```
 var the_points = points;
```

And points is just some array like ['10, 20', '100, 200'], so that assignment is equivalent to:

```
 var the_points = ['10, 20', '100, 200']
```

And inside the function you use the_points to refer to the array.

Comment: i thought posting the entire code would be overkill -- when i say the "stand alone" code works -- i mean this code works on a stand alone page and i can 'document.write' the values to the page -- so i know its grabbing them...i'm using the d3 plugin.

Comment: hi 7stud, thank you. yes, i am. i have included both scripts(in the correct order)on one page.  i just can't seem to get them to cooperate. i think i am just suffering from syntax dysfunction. -- i  want the "points" array built from the d3 function to become the "points: " array in pushpins(). so instead of pushpins() using values i've typed in (like this):  var points = { "points": ["47.15211, -97.570039","48.625045, 101.375369"]};
... 
i want it to instead use whatever is built in the loop from the d3().
-- maybe i should just stick to graphics and Photoshop. :(

Comment: No, it's just that you don't know the language to describe code, yet.  For instance, 'a page' is not used to describe a javascript.  We call a javascript file 'a script'.  In addition, presumably in the interests of brevity, you did not post any code that actually has your functions in it. A function starts with: function myfunc1(x,y,z) {....}.  Here is a tip: when you are having problems with a program, especially if you are a beginner, don't try to experiment in that program.  Instead, start another simple program, and experiment to find out how things work in a simple setting.

Comment: @ms.directed, Okay I posted the files.  You should ALWAYS have a set of files like this to experiment with when things start going wrong in your program.

Comment: THANK YOU @7stud for this - way beyond, i appreciate it!

Comment: @ms.directed, Did you get it to work( I had to remove some links to jquery javascripts) ?

Comment: i have created the sample files and i'm playing around with them now. (i included the links the the jquery cdn.) that was really nice to make those for me, thanks again!  i edited my question to be more 'correctly' asked, does it make more sense now? i'm trying to apply your suggestion to my project.

Comment: @ms.directed, Wait a minute, those links won't work for you.  I have a directory called 'lib' in the same directory as the files I posted, and the jquery scripts are in my 'lib' directory.

Comment: @ms.directed, Here are the links to the google hosted files: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>.  And if you would rather have them on your computer for development, just go to the jquery website and either copy and paste the source files or download them.

Comment: @ms.directed, What does d3.csv() return?  Is that a function you defined?  If not, can you point to the documentation for that function?

Comment: @ms.directed, I added a structure which I think will work for you situation.

Comment: you are awesome @7stud. the last part was the what i really couldn't get my head around, you explained it so well. you have been so generous  -- if you ever need some free graphics work, just let me know! i have worked for a popular bridal network tv show, i'm good at pretty pictures :)

Comment: @ms.directed, I'm glad everything worked out.  Thanks for the offer. Good luck with your programming.  I actually wanted to download those libraries and put together a working example, but I guess that deCarta stuff costs money?

Comment: in your example code -- do you mean the functions points() and the_points() to both be "the_points()"

Comment: I'll add my answer to my post, I hate writing code in the comments.

Comment: the deCarta stuff is "free" to use their API -- you can download it, i'm using the JS3 version -- you just have to sign up for a deCarta dev acct. deCarta.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to run through each pair in the array:

```
var points = [ "47.15211, -97.570039", "48.625045, -101.375369", "48.39679, -101.052669"];
points.forEach(function (point) {
  point = point.match(/^"([0-9\.]+)\s*,\s*([0-9\.]+)"$/);
  console.log('"' + point[0] + '", "' + point[1] + '"');
});
```

Or something like this if you're wanting to put them in their own arrays:

```
var points = [ "47.15211, -97.570039", "48.625045, -101.375369", "48.39679, -101.052669"],
    lat = [], lon = [];

points.forEach(function (point) {
  point = point.match(/^"([0-9\.]+)\s*,\s*([0-9\.]+)"$/);
  lat.push(point[0]);
  lon.push(point[1]);
});

lat.forEach(function (lat, id) {
  console.log('"' + lat + '", "' + lon[id] + '"');
});
```

Or even:

```
lon.forEach(function (lon, id) {
  console.log('"' + lat[id] + '", "' + lon + '"');
});
```

Also, someone commented on here and said that I shouldn't be using split for this when you're joining it back together. If you're not looking to have them separated like this, you can always use:

```
points.points = points.points.map(function (point) {
  return point.replace(/^"([0-9\.]+)\s*,\s*([0-9\.]+)"$/, '"$1", "$2"');
});
```

Comment: i will try all these suggestions, thank you SO much! anyone need Photoshop, CSS or DNN help? :0)

Comment: No problem. Just be sure to mark one of the answers you've gotten correct if it solves your problem. Also, look around for questions tagged with Photoshop, CSS, etc. to answer questions about them. :)

Comment: Also, I don't really understand what you mean in your updated question. You have hardcoded values that you want replaced? If they're just getting replaced, why do they need to be hardcoded?

Comment: Sly:  the 'hardcoded' values were just to test/demo the API, we had to make sure it was what we wanted to use.  Now i need the API to be fed 'dynamic' values -- i won't ever know the exact values of the lat & lon.

Comment: That shouldn't matter with these examples, as long as the API returns it in the same format as the values you had hardcoded.

Comment: i don't think i'm asking the right question, what if i want to send the API values from the d3 array, instead of values i've handcoded into the array? IOW, the values from the csv file, not the ones on the HTML page i typed in just for testing. (i promise it makes sense in my head)

Comment: So, you're saying that you want the values that are being pushed into the `lat` and `lon` arrays to be pushed into `points.points` with `"lat", "lon"` being the format in the array, or you're actually wanting it to be `[ lat, lon ]` in the array? Need specifics on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: "...you want the values that are being pushed into the lat and lon arrays to be pushed into points.points with "lat", "lon" -- " 

yes!! can i somehow just replace the "points" :[...]" part of the postPins() with the values from the d3() "var points = ('"' + lat[i] + "," + lon[i] + '"');" -- and have **that** be what is sent to the API?

Comment: Your whole `csv.map` function looks weird to begin with. Why are you calling `.toString()` on everything that you're pushing into an array? Also, you're only logging the very last result in the array with it being outside of the `for` loop. There's also no function here named `postPins`, so I don't know which one of your examples is the `postPins` function. Please make sure you post the full code example.

Comment: i thought i had to add the 'toString()' bc the data from the csv file has some issues -- extra blanks, numbers, extra commas...in my edited version above 'push pins()' is on **one** page -- 'd3.csv()' is on **another** page. i added a "+++++" to separate them.  the pushpins() was written first, then the d3.csv() was written later -- i just want to do in the pushpins() function 'for...' what the d3.csv() is doing in its 'for...'.  can i combine what these functions are doing so that they are doing it in **one** function?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work but I don't know what your variables rid, lat and long are. Maybe you could post it. To see the variable in Chrome or Firefox you can do:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(rid);
```

Press F12 to see the console.

```
var points={};
points.points=[];
for (i = 0; i < rid.length; i++) {
   points.points.push('"' + rid[i].lat + "," + rid[i].lon + '"');
}
```

Comment: "rid" is the column name for the "rowid" -- i wanted to be able to point to each row and use that as a divID. so when creating the csv file, the "rowID (rid)" is included. i will test your suggestion now, thank you very much!